# Dispatched data in useContext isnt updadet in all of my Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following problem. I try to get set State in one Component with useReducer.

That is my Component where I use the dispatch function:

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { Context } from "../state/context";
import { setTeams } from "../state/reducer";
import { RenderNavBar } from "./RenderNavBar";

export const GetTeamsByFiles = () => {
  const {state,dispatch}=useContext(Context);
  
  useEffect(() => {

    dispatch(setTeams([
      { name: "FKP1-Komplett", members: ["Lars", "Tobias", "Falko", "Sami"] },
      { name: "FKP1-Entwickler", members: ["Lars", "Tobias"] },
      {
        name: "FKP2-Komplett",
        members: ["Tessa", "Volker", "Robert", "Viktor", "Ahmed", "Patrick"],
      },
      {
        name: "FKP2-Entwickler",
        members: ["Tessa", "Volker", "Robert", "Viktor"],
      },
    ])
  )

      
  }, []);


  return (
    <>
      <RenderNavBar teams={state.teams}/>
    </>
  );
};
```

and I want to get access to the updated state in another Component with useContext

here you can see the component where I want to have my updated data

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useReducer ,useContext} from "react";
import { Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { Context } from "../state/context";

export interface IProps {
 
}
export const RenderCheckbox = () => {
  const {state}=useContext(Context);
  let { teamName }:any = useParams();

  useEffect(()=>{
   console.log(state)
  },[state])
  return (
    <>
    {teamName}
      <Form.Check
        type={"checkbox"}
        id={`default-checkbox`}
        label={`default checkbox`}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

That is my App Component.

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./App.css";
import { GetTeamsByFiles } from "./components/GetTeamsByFiles";
import { RenderCheckbox } from "./components/RenderCheckbox";

import { BrowserRouter, BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { useContext, useMemo, useReducer } from "react";
import { reducer } from "./state/reducer";
import { initialState } from "./state/state";
import { Context } from "./state/context";



function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Context.Provider value={{state,dispatch}}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={GetTeamsByFiles}></Route>
          <Route path="/:teamName" component={RenderCheckbox}></Route>
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Context.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And here is my created Context

```
import React from "react";
import { Actions } from "./actions";
import { initialState, State } from "./state";

export const Context = React.createContext<{
    state: State;
    dispatch: React.Dispatch<Actions>;
    }>({
        state: initialState,
        dispatch: () => undefined,
    });
```

Last but nor least my reducer

```
import { ITeam } from "../interfaces/ITeam";
import { Actions, ActionType, SetTeams } from "./actions";
import { State } from "./state";

export const reducer=(state: State, action: Actions): State=> {
  switch (action.type) {
      case ActionType.SetTeams:
      return { ...state, teams: action.payload };
      default:
      return state;
  }
}
export const setTeams = (teams: ITeam[]): SetTeams => ({
  type: ActionType.SetTeams,
  payload: teams,
});
```

It is updated in the first component but not in the second. What am I doing wrong?

Please be indulgent with me, its my first question on stack overflow :)

Which information more do you need to help me?

Comment: when you are changing the value in the context does both your first and second component was rendered ?

Comment: Don't share screenshot of your code in stackoverflow, you should always provide your code in text format

Comment: @Shyam the second component is rendered after the change in the context

Comment: @NicolasMenettrier  I hope thats better :)

Comment: @MNozdratchev My guess at your problem is that the state get lost when redirecting to /:teamName, I know for sure that redux provide a middleware called redux-persist that does what you want to achieve. Without redux I guess you'll have to store it in LocalStorage ? But i'm not sure. You should look at redux toolkit, it's way more convenient to use and it reduce the amount of code you need to produce.

Comment: I just checked for curiosity and redux-persist store a copy of the state inside LocalStorage, every time the App get rerendered (like when you redirect) it retrieve the state from it and fill the store

Comment: You shouldn't need localStorage for this as long as the navigation is correct. Your code seems legit, how to you handle navigation from `/` page to `/:teamName`? If you use simple html anchors (`<a>`) then the page is updated and the state is lost, you should use the `<Link>` component from `react-router-dom` instead. Otherwise, I can't really see any issues.
Without localStorage, of course, the state will be lost between page reloads, but not while navigating your application

Comment: @AlexChashin I used the href prop in the <NavDropdown.Item> component from Bootstrap. But it works with the <Link> component. Thank you!!